Arch linux RPi3 - AUR PKGBUILD Compile error
I've installed Arch arm linux (v7) on a micro SD and run it on a Rasberry Pi 3. Architecture armv7l it says.
All steps until this issue went well without errors.
I'm encountering this issue trying to build the package from the aur.archlinux.org site. The steps:

$ wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/ … ery.tar.gz
$ tar xfz package-query.tar.gz
$ cd package-query
$ makepkg   # here is the error

It states:
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See 'config.log' for mor details ==> ERROR: A failure occured in build() Aborting...
The config.log says things like:
unrecognized option -V, -qversion, -version, -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer
I can add the config.log file here if thats possible
I checked:

The dependencies needed by PKGBUILD (yajl, pacman) and checked their versions
Checked pacman -Syu, base-devel, gcc and make

I installed packages with pacman as root. The process described above (downloading, extracting and trying to build AUR package) I did as a normal user.
Who can help me? If I need to give additional information, please let me know.

First of all, armv7 is 32bit and the Pi3 is 64 bit. You can use the 64 bit image. Might (or might not) help. It's being mentioned at the bottom of the install manual page!
Secondly, the AUR is primarily for desktop and according architecture and x86 is pretty much 64 bit only these days. Meaning, compile errors are very likely for various reasons. Makepkg is the build and compilation process. So, no surprise there.
Thirdly, package-query is VERY outdated. AUR says last updated in 2021. Upstream GitHub says, latest changes 2 years ago. Newer system, older package...
Short, this is very likely not going to work and you should at least try to avoid this. Because even if you get it working now, without updates you might run into issues later. Also, besides the actual package management database in the system, Arch actually uses a quite simple system. You can just look into your mirrorlist file, get a server URL and browse stuff on the server to get a glimpse of repo stuff.
I'm not sure WHY you are trying to use this. If you are trying to use an AUR helper, my experience is, that yay has been working before and usually works. Yay too is outdated and you will likely have to re-compile with each upgrade. I have to do the same on desktop systems as well these days. But it should still work. Once again, it only works as far as default repos and ARM support goes in AUR. AUR is for desktop, not really ARM.
I've been using Arch Linux ARM for many years on a number of Raspberries. Be aware, that Arch Linux ARM is BY FAR not as well maintained as the desktop option and you will very likely run into issues if you change the system often (installs, upgrades, significant changes in packages...) or fall far behind and require upgrades that are further apart. Arch Linux ARM is great for specific purpose setups that don't change much though.
Also, be sure to store a backup of your operating system SD card. They are not supposed to storage data reliable beyond one or two years and WILL die every now and then and you have to require it. So, dd is your friend.
